# Normalizing Flows KL divergence equivalency

Tags: normalizing-flow

This question is related to the normalizing flows concept in machine learning.

Let $X \sim P_X$ and $U \sim P_U$ be, respectively, the distribution of the data and a base distribution (e.g. an isotropic gaussian). We define a normalizing flow as $F: \mathcal{U} \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ parametrized by $\theta$. Starting with $P_U$ and then applying $F$ will induce a new distribution $P_{F(U)}$ (used to match $P_X$). Since normalizing flows are invertible, we can also consider the distribution $P_{F^{-1}(X)}$.

How comes that in this case $D_{KL}[P_X || P_{F(U)}] = D_{KL}[P_{F^{-1}(X)} || P_U]$ ? $D_{KL}$ being the [Kullback–Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence).

Let's say there are 2 scenarios:

1. you don't have samples from $p_X(x)$, but you can evaluate $p_X(x)$,
2. you have samples from $p_X(x)$, but you cannot evaluate $p_X(x)$.

Which divergence should be used in each scenario as the objective to optimize?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question follows from the fact that the Kullback-Leibler divergence is, under mild conditions, invariant under transformations. This is straightforward and is shown [in the section "Properties" of the Wikipedia site that you have referred to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Properties).

The answer to your second question can be found in

> Papamakarios, George, et al. "Normalizing flows for probabilistic modeling and inference." Journal of Machine Learning Research 22.57 (2021): 1-64.

in sections 2.3.1 and 2.3.2.

What it says is basically this: If you can sample from $P_X$, you should minimize the KL-divergence:
$$
D_{KL}[P_X \| P_{F(U)}] = -\mathbb{E}_{P_X}[\log P_{F(U)}] - H_{P_X},
$$

where $H_{P_X}$ is the entropy of $P_X$. For the optimization task of finding the parameters of $F$ and $P_U$, the entropy is irrelevant, since it is constant. You can approximate the expectation $\mathbb{E}_{P_X}[P_{F(U)}]$ if you have samples of $P_X$, so this is appropriate for your second scenario.

For your first scenario, you should switch the arguments of the KL-divergence, i.e. you should minimize:
$$
D_{KL}[P_{F(U)} \| P_X] = \mathbb{E}_{P_U}[\log P_U] - \mathbb{E}_{P_U}[\log P_{F^{-1}(X)}]
$$

and since $P_U$ is considered to be easy to use, your only problem is to evaluate $P_{F^{-1}(X)}$, but that is considered doable in your first scenario.

Answer (score 1):

#### In short

The Kullback-Leibler divergence is the expectation value of the log-odds of two distributions

$$D_{KL}(A || B) = \textbf{E}_A\left[\log \left(\frac{P_A(x)}{P_B(x)} \right) \right]$$

or for continuous distributions

$$D_{KL}(A || B) = \textbf{E}_A\left[\log \left(\frac{f_A(x)}{f_B(x)} \right) \right]$$
When you transform both $A$ and $B$ in the same way with a one-to-one function, then the events in both transformed and non-transformed representations are exchangeable while the log-odds for specific events remain the same, and that is why the divergence remains the same.

---

#### Intuitive graphical view

The transformations used with normalizing flows are invertible and that requires that they are [one-to-one functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection). This means that volume under the curve of transformed elements remains fixed.

For example in the graph below the transformation is the quantile function of the standard normal which transforms the space $[0,1]$ to the line $\mathbb{R}$. The events $0.18<x<0.22$ and $0.45<x<0.49$ transform to respectively $-0.915<u<-0.772$ and $-0.126<u<-0.025$.

What you see is that the area under the curves relating to these events change width and height, but the total area remains the same.

In addition the relative ratio of the height two curves remains the same! The transformation changes the height of the distributions in the same way. The log-odds of events don't change.

[image: example of transformation]

The computation of the divergence will be an integral expressing a weighted sum/average of the log-odds $\log \left(\frac{f_A(x)}{f_B(x)}\right)$. For each contribution/weight of probability $f_A(x) dx$ you have an equivalent size weight $g_A(u) du$ with the same log-odds.

$$ \begin{array}{}
\int_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \log \left(\frac{f_A(x)}{f_B(x)}\right) f_A(x) dx &=& \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \text{LO}_X(x)  f_A(x) dx \\
&=&   \int_{u \in \mathcal{U}} \text{LO}_U(u)  f_A(x(u)) \frac{dx(u)}{du} du \\ 
&=&  \int_{u \in \mathcal{U}} \text{LO}_U(u)  g_A(u) du &=& \int_{u \in \mathcal{U}} \log \left(\frac{g_A(u)}{g_B(u)}\right) g_A(u) du \\
\end{array}$$

where $x(u)$ is the value of $x$ when we apply the reverse transformation to $u$.

#### One-to-one

An important requirement is that the transformation is one-to-one. This ensures that the transformation of the distribution density in terms of $x$ to the distribution density in terms of $u$ can be written as

$$g(u) = f(x(u)) \frac{dx(u)}{du} du $$

If multiple values of $x$ transform to a single $u$ then we would get a sum over all those values of $x$ that transform to $u$

$$g(u) = \sum_{i} f(x_i(u)) \left|\frac{\text{d}x_i(u)}{\text{d}u}\right|$$